# Markov Chain: Moving on a circle

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, markov-chains

> A particle moves on 12 points situated on a circle. At each step it is
>   equally likely to move one step in the clockwise or in the
>   counterclockwise direction. Find the mean number of steps for the
>   particle to return to its starting position.

Here is what I have tried:

Let $X_i$ be the event that the particle returns to its starting position given that it starts at $i$, then we have

$E[X_i]=\frac12E[X_{i-1}]+\frac12[X_{i+1}]=\frac12(\frac12(2)+\frac12E[X_{i+2}])+\frac12(\frac12(2)+\frac12E[X_{i-2}]$

which yields $E[X_i]=1+\frac12E[X_{i+2}]+\frac12E[X_{i-2}]$.

I am now stuck. How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my second attempt. Please feel free to comment on it:

Note that the above Markov chain is doubly stochastic, i.e. the sum of all entries in the same column sum up to $1$. Thus, the limiting probability $\pi_i$ for all $i$ should be $\frac1{12}$.

Now, $\pi_i$ being the limiting probability, we know that it is equal to $\frac1{m_{jj}}$, where $m_{jj}$ equals to the expected number of transitions required for state $j$ to return to state $j$. It now follows that the mean number of steps for particle to return to its starting position is $1/ (\frac1{12})=12$.

Comment: You should exploit the symmetry of the Markov chain and of the state space. Try to work out the case with 4 points on a circle case, then 6 points and then you should have understood how to solve the $2n$ points case.

Comment: @AleZok : Please see the above edit. I would also appreciate if you can put your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote with $1$ it's starting position. Let $h(i)$ be the expected number of steps to return to the position $1$ starting from position $i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots 12$. To avoid confusion it can be helpful to denote state $1$ (the initial state) as state $13$ when you visit it the second time. With this notation you have that $$h(1)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(2)+\frac{1}{2}h(12)$$ but $$h(13)=0$$ (since starting from $1$ you have first to move away (so $h(1)\neq0$) and then visit this state again in order to satisfy your target of returning (so $h(13)$ or $h(1')$ is equal to $0$). This gives you the set of equations $$\begin{cases}h(1)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(2)+\frac{1}{2}h(12)\\h(2)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(13)+\frac{1}{2}h(3)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(3)\\h(3)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(2)+\frac{1}{2}h(4)\\\ldots\\h(11)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(10)+\frac{1}{2}h(12)\\h(12)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(13)+\frac{1}{2}h(11)=1+\frac{1}{2}h(11)\\\end{cases}$$ which you can solve recursively to determine $h(1)$.

Comment: That means my first attempt can be continued to find a set of the above equations? What about my second attempt on using $m_{jj}$? Is it valid?

Comment: @LeeKM Yes to both. Actually your second attempt is very fine, keep that one.

Answer (score 1):

You should exploit the symmetry of the Markov chain and of the state space. Try to work out the case with 4 points on a circle, then 6 points and then you should have understood how to solve the case of $2n$ points on circle.